# Failed to Create Snapshot in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, git-submodules

Does Xcode 4 have a problem with creating a snapshot for a project with git submodules?

fatal: Path 'path/to/project/vendor/facebook-ios-sdk/src' is in submodule 'path/to/project'

Now, this error message is also wrong, if it refers to git submodule. The 'path/to/project' is not a git submodule.

Next:

1. I tried to delete the snapshot, and try to create it again. This is successful.
2. I try to create a new snapshot (while an existing snapshot is there). This is failed.

Comment: It almost seems to be succeeding even when it says it fails. Maybe it just fails for that submodule?

Comment: Not sure. But, when I tried to restore from the snapshot, it doesn't work. Anyway, this issue has been reported to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem today with Xcode 4.2 (4D199) after changing the folder structure of my project. I fixed it by taking the following steps:

- Make sure all files and folders in your project are added or ignored in the repository
- Choose "Organizer" in the "Window" menu
- Choose "Projects" in the organizer
- Choose your project in the sidebar
- Delete all snapshots of the project

WARNING: Export snapshots before you delete them, if you want to use them later!

Comment: Odd, I can't seem to solve this issue.  I've clean up any orphans in Git and deleted all my snapshots, yet I'm still getting freaky errors like this upon creating a snapshot.

Comment: i did these steps, reinstalled xcode, and still no luck, it ended up being that the .git directory was up one directory more then it should have been.  as soon as i moved it everything worked

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue. moving the project folder to another location worked for me (there was a  * in a folder name further up the directory chain where the project was located in (like this /***myprojects/iphoneprojects/wontsnapshoproject), as soon as renamed the folder with the * it worked (/myprojects/iphoneprojects/wontsnapshoproject).